# Are there any ATMs on the transit side of Incheon Airport?

Tags: money, transit, atms, icn

Are there any ATMs or currency exchanges on the transit side of Incheon Airport?  We're passing through but are staying overnight in the transit hotel.  Is there anywhere to get won from on that side, or will we be limited to credit card usage if we don't bring our own?

Comment: No,they have not. And boy do they get testy when you ask. Actually most of the people I asked were not irritated, but the last two people I asked got really hissy with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Lonely Planet forums](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1880892):

> Transit passengers who do not clear customs will not have access to
>   any ATM in Incheon Airport.
>
> The only ATMs at Incheon airport are outside the sacred circle of
>   customs. So if you need cash when you land at Incheon, you have to
>   clear customs.

There are two currency exchanges on the transit side that will exchange money into Korean won, as well as most stores/restaurants accepting US dollars and some other currencies.

Comment: @dlanod - possibly.  That was the most up to date information I could find.  Will have another look this morning, but AFAIK that's the best. Perhaps you can update when you go if you happen to find any.  The thing is, you won't be the first, so surely the transit hotel would have mechanisms for dealing with this.